# How would I loop through a multiple branch json array using jquery without limiting results to single array?

Tags: jquery, json

This is probably a very simple question but I am learning and having trouble figuring this out.

Basically I have my current code:

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data[0].user.products, function () {
      $("table").append($("<tr>").append(
        $("<td>").addClass("Title").text(this.stock),
      ));
    });
});
```

Within my JSON I have multiple branches. How would I loop through each branch instead of just [0]?

```
data[0].user.products
data[1].user.products
data[2].user.products
data[3].user.products
data[4].user.products
```

Thanks in advance for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another loop.

```js
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, d) {
    $.each(d.user.products, function () {
      $("table").append($("<tr>").append(
        $("<td>").addClass("Title").text(this.stock),
      ));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks much. Could you explain what the "d" does or is this just a variable placeholder?

Comment: It's the parameter to the function that contains the current element in the loop.

Comment: You could also use `this` like you do in the loop you wrote.

Comment: Ok I see, I thought so. I wasn't aware it was interchangeable. TIL. Thanks much

Comment: I must have been confused, always used this. I feel dumb now. ha

Answer (score 1):

You can directly loop through `data` array and then do the current loop on `products` array and access the value `stock` like:

```
$.each(data, function(_, v1) {
   $.each(v1.user.products, function(_, v2) {
      $("table").append($("<tr>").append(
         $("<td>").addClass("Title").text(v2.stock),
      ));
   });
});
```

Comment: You forgot a closing }); but non the less your approach also helped me out immensely. Thank you so much!